# How to do Typescript regex replace and extract value in the same time?

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I'd like to change path =  `'a.0.b.c.e.f.11.d.20'` to `'a[0].b.c.e.f[11].d[20]'`

I was thinking to use something like : `replace(/\.\d+/g , '.[${d+}]')`;

But this is not working. How can I replace the .number with with value .[number]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After matching a period, *capture* digits in a group, then replace with those digits in brackets using the capture group:

```js
console.log(
  'a.0.b.c.e.f.11.d.20'
    .replace(/.(\d+)/g, '[$1]')
);
```